# How to handle exceptions using LINQ's SubmitChanges method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, exception

I am adding a new record to my department table using LINQ, this what I do:

```
try
{
    dpt = new departement();
    dpt.departementcode = tbDepartementCode.Value;
    dpt.departementname = tbDepartementName.Value;
    dpt.createby = "hendra";
    dpt.createdate = DateTime.Now;
    dpt.updateby = "hendra";
    dpt.lastupdate = DateTime.Now;

    Linq.departements.InsertOnSubmit(dpt);
    Linq.SubmitChanges(); // error happen here, and could not catch it.

    Response.Redirect("Departement.aspx");
}
catch (ChangeConflictException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is, even after using `try` and `catch` I still get an error screen when I enter a record which already exists in the database. How to fix it? Any ideas? Some example would be great.

Comment: Fix the problem with your `//Make some adjustments` code. If an exception occurs there it won't recurse back into the `catch` and handle it.

Comment: What is the full exception that you receive?

Comment: Can you show us (1) the whole exception, incl. the type and stacktrace and (2) the whole method (since in your prev. example you had more catch-blocks, and now I am only seeing one.)

Answer (score 2):

If you try to submit your changes again inside the catch block, it could produce a new exception. The catch block you are already in, catch that new exception. For the new exception to be caught, you have to define a new try-catch inside your catch.

**EDIT**

Since the question has changed, if the catch is not catching the exception which is thrown inside `Linq.SubmitChanges()`, than the thrown exception is probably not of the type `ChangeConflictException`.

Comment: the problem is, error happen after this code : Linq.departements.InsertOnSubmit(dpt);
 Linq.SubmitChanges();

Comment: Then it's a different exception that's occurring, not the one your are catching

Comment: i've edited my post, put mark on where error occurs, any ideas how to fix that? btw i tried to use catch general exception, but it does not work too.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint to ensure it isn't *entering* the catch block?

Comment: nah it's working now, i use general exception to catch it, anyway thx everyone.

Comment: Good to know it is working. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @HendraLim, you mentioned before that you have already tried catching general exceptions but it didn't work - care to share what you did differently?

Answer (score 1):

> I still get an error screen when I enter a record which already exists in the database

So check your database first if the data exists, if it exists update old data, else add new data.

```
try
{
    // Check Database first with your primary key, lets assume your check returned a
    // with dptcheck

    var dptcheck = from d in Linq.departments
                   where d.YourPrimaryKey == YourValue
                   select d;

    dpt = new departement();

    if (dptcheck.Any()) dpt = dptcheck.FirstOrDefault();

    dpt.departementcode = tbDepartementCode.Value;
    dpt.departementname = tbDepartementName.Value;
    dpt.createby = "hendra";
    dpt.createdate = DateTime.Now;
    dpt.updateby = "hendra";
    dpt.lastupdate = DateTime.Now;

    if (!dptcheck.Any()) Linq.departements.InsertOnSubmit(dpt); 
    // notice you only insert data if no old value found
    Linq.SubmitChanges();

    Response.Redirect("Departement.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below mention code it may help you.

```
 Context.SubmitChanges(Result =>
         {

             if (Result.HasError)
                 {
                 CallBack(Result.Error.ToString());
                 }
             else
                 {
                 CallBack("Done");
                 }
         }, null);
```

Comment: This does not compile: No overload for method 'SubmitChanges' takes 2 arguments